# jquery cycle curtainX not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, cycle

I'm having a problem with my 'curtainX' cycle animation in jquery. The first animation seems to zoom out in the top center, instead of doing the animation it should. I can't seem to find the problem and now I don't know where to start. I tried checking the different options for the animations and can't seem to figure it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type = "text/css">img{position:absolute;}</style>
    <script src = "jquery.js"></script>
    <script src = "jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src = "jquery-cycle.js"></script>
    <script src = "text/javascript">
      function start(){
        $("#blank").cycle({
          fx: 'curtainX',
          sync: false,
          delay: -4000
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id = "blank" onclick = "start()">
      <img src = "img/blank.gif" style = "z-index:1"/>
      <img src = "img/1c.gif"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can view a demo at http://vrbj.webs.com/flipTest.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem related to the absence of a width and a height.

I've rewritten the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Btxuu/1/)

Removing width and height causes your problem.

You can solve changing:

```
img{position:absolute;}
```

to

```
img{position:absolute; width: 59px; height: 74px;}
```

Consider also the way you have written your code, taking a loo at what i've written.
Your code's right but the way is written is less "plugin's compliant" than in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in the  tag are called when they are needed. Try moving your start function within the  tag and put that within an $(document).ready( your function ) call